# Current test case success/failure

Tags: swift, xctest

I have a *XCTestCase* that is writing some asset that I would like to clean if it success. I discover that there is a static *tearDown()* method that I can override which is executed at the end of the test case. How can I know if the test case succeeded or not?

Comment: Do you want to know that to display a custom log message ?

Comment: Not I want to make some cleanup in case of success.

Answer (score 2):

XCTestObserver is now deprecated so you should use the `XCTestObservationCenter`.

You should implement an `observer` that conforms to `XCTtestObservation`.

`XCTestObservationCenter.sharedTestObservationCenter().addTestObserver(observer)`

Apple's staff quote in [XCTestObservation.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-xctest/blob/master/Sources/XCTest/XCTestObservation.swift):

> Hooks for being notified about progress during a test run.

You can find how to handle testCaseDidFinish in [Print Observer](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-xctest/blob/master/Sources/XCTest/PrintObserver.swift#L47-L59)

```
func testCaseDidFinish(_ testCase: XCTestCase) {
    let testRun = testCase.testRun!
    let verb = testRun.hasSucceeded ? "passed" : "failed"
    // FIXME: Apple XCTest does not print a period after "(N seconds)".
    //        The trailing period here should be removed and the functional
    //        test suite should be updated.
    printAndFlush("Test Case '\(testCase.name)' \(verb) (\(formatTimeInterval(testRun.totalDuration)) seconds).")
}
```

Comment: Where shall I run the *addTestObserver()* method so it is executed before the test bundle start?

Answer (score 1):

`XCTest` has a property, `testRun`, which returns the `XCTestRun` for your test, which has a `hasSucceeded` property.

http://masilotti.com/xctest-documentation/Classes/XCTestRun.html

Comment: I'm dealing with `XCTestCase` not `XCTest`, how can I get this `testRunClass` property?

Comment: XCTestCase is a subclass of XCTest so it should be accessible from both? http://masilotti.com/xctest-documentation/Classes/XCTestCase.html

Comment: It's almost working but I'm struggling converting the `testRunClass` property to `XCTestRun` instance, any idea?

Comment: Oops, sorry! Looks like you need `testRun` on XCTest, which returns the instance of XCTestRun used to run your test, and you should be able to call `.hasSucceeded` on that. I'll update my answer.